# How can I prove these quantifier problem? $\neg\forall x P(x) \iff \exists x \neg P(x)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, first-order-logic, quantifiers, formal-proofs

I am taking a discrete mathematics course in a college now, and studying about the negation of quantifiers. I understood it is correct directly, but want to know how to prove it. Could someone prove it?

There are many proofs of below problems, but I want the proof consists of some statements or sentences like this "$\neg\forall x P(x) \iff \exists x \neg P(x)$".

Below are the problems.

$$
\neg\forall x P(x) \iff \exists x \neg P(x)
$$

$$
\neg\exists x P(x) \iff \forall x \neg P(x)
$$

Comment: How do you want to prove them?  Using the semantical definition of the logical operators, or through a formal derivation (formal proof)? Or ...?

Comment: I would like the proof derived with a formal way. Also the method of using logical operators would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof of the first equivalence in the Fitch system:

[image]